# .parent().parent().parent() vs .closest("li")

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

When searching the DOM, which is preferable?

```
var li = el.parent().parent().parent();
```

or

```
var li = el.closest("li");
```

Assuming the parent `<li>` will always be exactly 3 elements above.

Comment: `closest` wins for readability!

Comment: I believe the answer to your question may be found here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264954/which-is-more-efficient-parent-parent-parent-or-parents-foo-or-c?rq=1

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264954/which-is-more-efficient-parent-parent-parent-or-parents-foo-or-c?rq=1

Comment: In my experience, statements like, "the parent `<li>` will always be exactly 3 elements above" end up not being true. So `closest('li')` gets my vote.

Comment: Well technically `.parent()...` is faster, but `.closest()` reads better. http://jsperf.com/multiple-parent-vs-closest

Comment: Migrate to Code Review maybe?

Comment: Ben, thanks, I hadn't thought to try jsperf.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `.closest()`

- Higher separation of concerns - won't break the  behavior (JS) due to minor structure change - that is, wrapping the target element in a `<div>` or `<span>` for styling;
- Readability - indicates the final target (common ancestor) more clearly;
- DRY/shorter code.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm voting to close ('primarily opinion based'), I'd always suggest `closer()`, for both readability and because it abstracts the code away from the precise structure of the DOM; so wrapping the starting element in another element won't cause it to break, and nor will removing a wrapping element.