# Different between parents() and closest parent()

Tags: jquery

I don't understand very well the difference, in the case that there is only one my_class class in the dependency tree, between :

```
$(this).parent().closest('.my_class').attr('id');
```

And

```
$(this).parents('.my_class').attr('id')
```

Is there actually any difference ?

EDIT: no this no duplicate as here I take the example of only one my_class in the dependency tree. I know that parent() returns only one element when parents() return the list of matching elements, and that closest() can return "this" if it matches the filter.

HTML example :

```
<div class="agenda_relative">
    <div class="agenda_day" data-date="<?php echo $year."-".$m."-".$d; ?>">
            <div class="agenda_day_nr"><?php echo $d; ?></div>      
               <ul class="agenda_hour">
                    <?php foreach ($date->hours as $h): ?>
                        <li><?php echo $h; ?><p class='agenda_hour_input' data-hour="<?php echo $h; ?>" contenteditable="true"></p>
```

On event blur on the  I want to get the data('date') of the agenda_day div

I have the working solution, but I wonder if there is any difference between the 2 methods above

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which is more efficient: .parent().parent().parent() ~or~ parents(".foo") ~or~ closest(".foo")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264954/which-is-more-efficient-parent-parent-parent-or-parents-foo-or-c)

Comment: What's the HTML look like?

Comment: Pls see edit, my question is slightly different than the one you found, that's why I ask it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there actually any difference ?

Not in the `id` value you get, no.

But although they get the same result, they do different things:

- `$(this).parent().closest(".my_class")` builds three jQuery objects, the last of which has at most one element in it.
- `$(this).parents(".my_class")` builds two jQuery objects, the last of which potentially has several elements in it, which are in order according to how close they are to `this` (the first entry is the nearest one). Of course, you've said that only one `.my_class` can exist in your scenario, so in *your specific case* you'll get at most one element there as well. But in the general case, even if there were nested `my_class` elements, you'd still get the right `id`.

There's also a difference in terms of how much traversal occurs: In the second case, even once it's found the parent, jQuery will still keep traversing up the ancestry looking for more of them (because although you know there aren't any more to find, jQuery doesn't, so it goes ahead and looks). In the first case, it'll stop with the first one it finds.

Comment: "in the case that there is only one my_class class in the dependency tree"

Comment: It matters because I already know what you wrote, and I specifically wants to know if in such cases there is a real difference between parents() and parent().closest(xxxx)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edit, that's exactly what I needed to know :)

Comment: @VincentTeyssier: np. I just added a note about traversal as well, which I *meant* to include, but somehow didn't originally.

Comment: Thanks, I have a very heavy project and efficiency gain is always appreciable :)

Comment: @VincentTeyssier: In that case, if you know `this` will never have `my_class` (I don't know if you know that, but if you do), probably just `$(this).closest(".my_class")` would be best. Saves creating an extra jQuery object.

Comment: Indeed^^ Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `.my_class` is not on the current element too, you actually just want:

```
$(this).closest('.my_class').attr('id');
```

The other two grab varying numbers of matching element (parent only gets the immediate `parent` element, `parents` gets all ancestors, `closest` stops on the first match).

Comment: So theoritically in such cases, there is no difference at all between parents() and parent().closest(xxxx) ?

Comment: The second is more efficient. `parents()` could potentially return multiple matches. `parent().closest()` will match one at most and stop earlier so is more efficient.

Comment: Indeed. And even if it doesn't return multiple matches, it still has to go looking for them (since *it* doesn't know it won't find them).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder. I meant multiples prior to the `attr` call, as they are wasted, but I see you covered it already in your answer :)